# Always Encrypted: Como inserir em coluna criptografada?

Tags: sql, sql-server, criptografia

Primeiro eu tentei isso:

```
DECLARE @test varchar(50) = 'test'
insert into Customer values ('Lucas', 'Test', @test)
```

Mas deu esse erro:

```
Encryption scheme mismatch for columns/variables '@test'. The encryption scheme for the columns/variables is (encryption_type = 'PLAINTEXT') and the expression near line '3' expects it to be (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'MyCEK', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'AlwaysEncrypted') (or weaker).
```

Depois eu tentei isso:

```
insert into Customer values ('Lucas', 'Test', 'test')
```

E deu esse erro dessa vez:

```
Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with varchar(8000) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'MyCEK', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'AlwaysEncrypted') collation_name = 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS'
```

Meus scripts para geração da coluna criptografada:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].Customer
ADD [EncryptedValue] [varchar](50) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2
    ENCRYPTED WITH(
        ENCRYPTION_TYPE = DETERMINISTIC,
        ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256',
        COLUMN_ENCRYPTION_KEY = MyCEK) NOT NULL

CREATE COLUMN ENCRYPTION KEY MyCEK   
WITH VALUES  
  (  
    COLUMN_MASTER_KEY = MyCMK,   
    ALGORITHM = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256',   
    ENCRYPTED_VALUE = 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
  )

CREATE COLUMN MASTER KEY MyCMK  
WITH (  
     KEY_STORE_PROVIDER_NAME = N'MSSQL_CERTIFICATE_STORE',   
     KEY_PATH = 'Current User/Personal/f2260f28d909d21c642a3d8e0b45a830e79a1420'  
   );
```

Comment: faça o comando insert completo, informando o nome das colunas, e tenha certeza de que todas as colunas com encryption são passadas usando variáveis

Comment: Lembrando que essa opção `Always Encrypted` foi inclusa na versão do SqlServer 2016, ou seja, não está disponível em versões anteriores.

Comment: Conseguiu achar uma solução?

Comment: Ainda não, consegui inserir mas o dado não está sendo criptografado